# favicon not showing up in directory

Tags: directory, favicon

I have a directory that needs to show my company's favicon when you see the directory index that looks like this:

[image]

as you can see, favicon.ico is in the folder, but the favicon of the company this is hosted with is displaying in the browser. I searched online for an answer but i found nothing. I really don't have any idea how to do this, and i'm sure there's a way... is it apache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to need to have the following directive in your Apache config:

```
AddType image/x-icon .ico
```

As far as it showing up in the directory index, I'm not sure it will work because you normally need to add this bit of HTML to inform the browser that a favicon exists:

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

You may be able to modify the template used by Apache to display directory indexes, but I don't know where it is (or even if it's possible to modify, honestly)

Comment: where is this apache file found?

Comment: depends on the OS - try googling for your server OS + location of httpd.conf.

Answer (score 0):

For some odd reason, the favicon can take along time to show up in the browser. I would say you shouldn't really be concerned until 24 to 48 hours after you've changed the icon.

Comment: this has been about a month, and i keep trying new stuff (and putting it off)